# Building custom multi-level menus in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anybody know of a way to get more than a single level within a custom menu in Google Spreadsheet Apps Script?

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#addMenu) it shows how to add a single level menu using `method addMenu(menuName, menuEntries)`. Can `menuEntries` be structured to give a menu hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

Now it is impossible to create the multilevel menus. There is an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=317) submitted to the GAS issues tracker. You can vote for this issue. Hopefully the GAS team will fix this topic soon.

Comment: The issue was fixed.